# Is there a standard formulation of a 'null element'?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, reference-request, universal-algebra

I want to define the set $F$ of functions on a set $X$ that can be generated from a finite number of selected operations defined on $X$ (the set from which these operations are selected need not be finite, but each function needs to expressible using a finite number of operations).

At first I had considered a subset of the infinite product...

$$F(X)\subseteq X^X=\prod_{x\in X}X$$

...for which $f\in F(X)$ is a function (whose value at $x$ is $f(x)=f_x$) but then I realized that said product does not include obvious cases where a function is undefined at a point in its domain, for example $f(0)$ where $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C};\ f(z)=1/z$.

The easiest solution I could think of was to define a 'nonelement' $\bot$ so that if $f:X\to X$, then $f(x)\ \text{undefined}\iff f(x)=\bot$. This is basically saying that the set of solutions $y$ to the equation $y=f(x)$ is empty. For example, I might have $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C};\ f(z)=1/z\implies f(0)=\bot$.

Then I can modify the product accordingly to include functions which are undefined at some point...

$$F(X)\subseteq\prod_{x\in X}X\cup\{\bot\}$$

Obviously, there are some problems with having such a 'null element' a few of which were addressed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2051779/is-there-a-non-standard-set-theory-that-makes-use-of-a-null-element), but none of them are too daunting on their own. The real difficulty is getting various definitions to work together. I can see a lot of use for a null element, so imagine someone has already done this. Is there an accepted convention for such an element? are there any sources which look at it in detail?

---

Abstract/universal algebra tag is for context - If $(X,S_{op})$ is the algebraic structure consisting of the set $X$ and the collection of operations $S_{op}$, then $F(X)$ as described above is the equivalent of the class of elementary functions in $(X,S_{op})$.

Comment: Functions $A\to B\cup\{0\}$ correspond to *partial mappings* $A\leadsto B$ (functions not necessarily defined on all $A$), provided $0\notin B$. The term *null element* usually rather refers to the additive identity element in an Abelian (semi-)group. Your $F$ is then basically a *finitely generated subsemigroup* of $(X\cup\{0\})^X$.

Comment: @Berci Okay, that was a mistake on my part. When I said *null element*, I meant an element with no inherent value. I'm not sure what terminology I should be using.

Comment: @Berci In any case, it is not necessary that $X$ is a group, but *if* $X$ is a semigroup, then yes - $F$ would be a be a subsemigroup of $(X\cup\{\})^X$. More generally, $F$ is a substructure of some algebraic structure $(X,S_{op})$, which may have any number of operations. $S_{op}$ might form a group under partial composition, though, I'll have to think about it.

Comment: IMO the idea of extending a function from $B\to C$ to $A\to C$ where $B\subseteq A$ this way is sensible, but I think the idea of making a big deal about the adjoined element being "null" is a little distracting. Honestly you just need one distinguished element not in any of the sets involved. I think you can get the point across that it is "where you map things that haven't already been defined" without calling it a "non-element element." Maybe something that expresses the sense of "an element we've picked that isn't an element of any of the sets we're talking about" is closer to the truth.

Comment: I think some computer scientists use $\bot$ to denote this element when it can't be confused with the logical symbol

Comment: The category of such sets and mappings is called the category of [pointed sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointed_set). Interestingly enough this is apparently equivalent but not isomorphic to the category of partial functions, according to wikipedia.